# I need to subtract value from the array

Tags: c#

I need to substract given sum from array of elements. I.e. if given value is 15 and array starts with [10, 20,...] I need to substract 10 from the first elements (resulting with 0 for it) and the rest continue to subsequent elements - so second would be decreased by 5 (15 - 10), and the rest stay untouched.

```
int[] myNum = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
```

if given value is `15` then I need to subtract value from the array. The new array will be

```
int[] myNum=[0,5,30,40]
```

I can easily create new array with *all* elements of the array decreased by the given number with basic `for` loop, but I don't know how to change that number based on how much I already substracted.

Comment: Substract 15 while 10 => 0 & 20 => 5 & 30 => 30 & 40 => 40 ? What is the logic ? What are the rules ? How about any other values and number of values ? Otherwise just use a loop like: `for ( int index = 0; index < myNum.Length; index++ ) myNum[index] = myNum[index] - WhatYouWant;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is a `for` loop.
This will allow you to perform an action (I.E subtraction) on each 'element' of an array.
By using a `return` statement, you can return the new array that has had each element modified

**EDIT** As per @AlexeiLevenkov's comment, I have updated my answer to keep a count of the remaining subtraction.
[Using this to test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = new int[]{5,10,15,20,25,30,35};
        array=SubtractArray(array,25);
        Console.WriteLine("Output is:");
        foreach(int v in array){
            Console.WriteLine(v+", ");
        }
    }
    public static int[] SubtractArray(int[] array , int subtraction){
        for(int i=0; i< array.Length;i++){
            if(subtraction>0){
                int newValue=array[i]-subtraction;
                if(newValue<1){
                    newValue=0;
                    subtraction=subtraction-array[i];
                }
                array[i]=newValue;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the input provided in the question this code results in "Output is:
0, 
5, 
15, 
25, " - while OP clearly said that expected "[0,5,30,40]".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov right you are, I will adjust it now!

Comment: Ohhhh... Now I see what OP was asking about :)

Comment: if (subtraction > 0)
                {
                    int newValue = array[i] - subtraction;
                    if (newValue < 1)
                    {
                        newValue = 0;
                        subtraction = subtraction - array[i];
                    }
                   array[i] = newValue;
                    if (newValue > 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

Comment: @KokilaSanjeewa what is your question?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know wath you said but I think it that :

The Arrays work 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

if I made a arrays like that

```
int[] _int = {10, 50, 30};
```

for go to the fist (10) and substract I need to do that

- Sorry for my english I'm french

  _int[0] -= 10;

becose it will select automatic the first (0)